# Count and print Triplets in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given a sorted array of n integers,  display  triplets such that a[i] < a[j] < a[k].
My code is

```
public static void countTriplets(int arr[], int index, int arr1[], int position)
{
    if (position == 3)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr1[position] = arr[i];
        countTriplets(arr, index + 1, arr1, position + 1);
    }
}
```

However it prints all possible triplets.Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Given the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, what would you expect the result to be? Given the array `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, what would you expect the result to be? Also, given those two arrays, what is the output from your program?

Comment: Duplicates should be eliminated

Comment: Title and description mention one array. In your uncommented code, `countTriplets` takes two as parameters - which is what you are after? What is to happen to the count of triplets? Also, don't use `System.out`: use an `Appendable`.

Comment: I'll repeat: show sample input and expected output. We shouldn't have to play 20 questions with you just to figure out what the heck you're trying to do.

Comment: No duplicates contained in I/P.
I/P : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
O/P:  [1,2,3]
      [1,2,4]
      [1,2,5]
............
............
............
      [2,3,4]
.......
      [3,4,5]

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of *unique* elements in the array. Let it be 'N'. Then the answer is n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6.

The reasoning is as follows: for any three distinct numbers a, b, c, we can form a tuple of sorted elements such that say b < c < a. Since we don't want repetitions, we have to count the number of unique elements.

For example, consider {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6}
Number of unique elements = 6. The answer is (6 * 5 * 4) / 6 = 20.

Some code in C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int count_triplets(int *a, int n)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (n < 3) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // jump to the last of the repeated values
        if ((i < n - 1) && (a[i] == a[i + 1])) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            // jump to the last of the repeated values
            if ((j < n - 1) && (a[j] == a[j + 1])) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                // jump to the last of the repeated values
                if ((k < n - 1) && (a[k] == a[k + 1])) {
                    continue;
                }
                printf("[%d, %d, %d]\n", a[i], a[j], a[k]);
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter the number of elements:");
    int n = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    int a[100] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    int triplets = count_triplets(a, n);

    printf("Number of triplets = [%d]\n", triplets);

    return 0;
}
```

This is not the most efficient but should lead you to more efficient solutions.

Comment: What about printing the triplets ?

Comment: Ah the question says count and display _number_ of triplets, not the triplets themselves. I'll update with the display code.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is with nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-2; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length-1; j++)
    {
        for (int k = j+1; k < arr.length; k++)
        {
            // output the triplet arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]
            ++numTriplets;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will do what you're asking. It does not take into account the possibility of duplicates in the source array. Given the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, it outputs:

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
1,3,4
1,3,5
1,4,5
2,3,4
2,3,5
2,4,5
3,4,5
```

### Update

The general solution to this problem is one of creating combinations. That is, selecting combinations of `n` items from a list of size `m`. The math tells us that the number of combinations is equal to:

```
   m!
---------
(n!)(m-n)!
```

Substituting numbers for your example, we have:

```
c = 5!/((3!) * (5-3)!)
  = 120/(6 * 2)
  = 120/12
  = 10
```

So you can *compute the number of combinations* in O(1) easily enough (if you use an [approximation for the factorial function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html)), but if you want to enumerate them your time complexity approaches O(m!) (for sufficiently large values of `m`).

You certainly can't enumerate all the combinations in O(n) or O(n log n). That would be kind of like asking for an algorithm that can enumerate all n-digit numbers in O(n) or O(n log n).

Comment: Let us consider that The input has no duplicates

Comment: @JimMischel This doesnt generate all triplets but only consecutive triplets

Comment: By any means, can we do it in O(N) or O(N*logN) ?

Comment: @KoustavChatterjee: Not possible. See my updated answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the answer can be reduced to selection of three numbers from n numbers which is nc3 i.e 
return (n*(n-1)*(n-2))/3! where n>=3 else return 0

Comment: What about printing the triplets ?